# Добрый день, интересует проблема eof в std::ifstream, но индикатор на eof видимо работает некорректно, из-за чего цикл становится бесконечным

Tags: c++, файловый-ввод-вывод

```
while (!fin.eof())
{
    fin.read(&arr[count], size);
    count += fin.gcount();
    if(fin.gcount() == size)
    {
        overSize += size;
        std::unique_ptr<char[], decltype(std::free) *> temp(static_cast<char *>(realloc(arr.get(), overSize)), std::free); // просто чтение в некий массив расширяемый
        arr.release();
        std::swap(arr, temp);
    }
}
```

В чем проблема данного цикла?

Comment: Проверка на `eof` должна быть после попытки чтения.

Comment: Пробовали искать похожие вопросы перед заданием нового?

Comment: Проверяйте позицию указателя на файле, или смотрите ваш счётчик - сравнивайте с размером файла. Вы не указали деталей. Во первых ваш алгоритм при size <= 0 - зависнет. Во вторых если у вас count - 32-битное, а файл более 4GB - то будет не правильно считать. И в третьих, если файл больше 100 МB а порции маленькие - алгоритм может работать очень много, и более часа.

Comment: А вообще трассируйте и смотрите значение переменных. Отладте программу на маленьких файлах размером size, потом size*2, а потому уже проверяйте для других. Но большие файлы всёравно возможно будет медленно читать.

Comment: Нашему  EOF у видней когда нужно проверять на eof....